# Rename API endpoint from .php to .json

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, post

A service is trying to access my API by sending a GET request.

*https://oberlo.com/fetch_stock.json?sku=123&shop=testshop.myshopify.com*

The REST API on Wordpress doesn't understand the .json extension.

How do I respond to a a GET request ending in .json with PHP?

Comment: Why must it be a `.json` extension? Surely this API on Wordpress can get a JSON result from a PHP file. A `.json` file, I doubt, can actually execute PHP without a lot of modifications under the hood of your server.

Comment: These are non-negotiable requests sent by Shopify. They will send a .json extension! (I wish it was a webhook haha) @GrumpyCrouton

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/shipping-and-fulfillment/fulfillmentservice

Comment: This should be of interest: https://serverfault.com/q/739577/255167

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton There is nothing explicitly special about invoking the PHP interpreter for files which do not end in `.php`. It just happens to be that sending `.php` files to PHP is default behavior.

Comment: RewriteRule, MultiViews or SetHandler are all options.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes, by "modifications under the hood", I meant making the interpreter execute `.json` as PHP, while also not breaking anything else on the server.